# (thymeleaf button + spring) button using cell value

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm having quite a struggle sending a table cell value to a spring controller using thymeleaf.

I want to submit the cell 'id' of the current row into a spring endpoint, using a get request.

What am i doing wrong? This is my current code (simplified):

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align: center">Text</th>
            <th style="text-align: center">Id</th>  
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr th:if="${results.empty}">
            <td colspan="2">No entries</td>
        </tr>

        <tr th:each="result : ${results}">
            <td th:text="${result.text}"></td>
            <td>
               <button type="submit" th:action="@{/entry/delete} + '?id=' + ${result.id}" method="get">Delete</button>
           </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution. It was a syntax issue.

Working code, in case someone bumps into the same problem:

```
<a class="button" th:href="@{/entry/delete(id=${result.id})}">  
    <button>Delete</button>
</a>
```